# Regex To Parse Anything Not A \b

Tags: .net, regex

Have some text files that I need to break out the individual words.  But with a very liberal definition of word.

`\b` seems to correctly identify the boundaries but since it is zero width ^\b does not do anything.

I know .NET string.parse might be faster but I need the match position also.

What I ended up with is shown below.  When with ^ on non zero that I wanted to breaks on.  Added date, email, and URL that wanted to ignore breaks.

I know that solution is not very close to my original problem statement.  It evolved.  Thank you all for your help.

```
    String line;
pattern = @"\w+@\w+|[01]?\d\/[0123]?\d\/([12]\d)?\d\d|https?:\/\/(?:\w+\.){1,3}\w+|[^\s\.\\///?!()@,]{2,200}";
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(line);
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(line, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(match.Index.ToString() + " " + match.Value);
        }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Please add a sample string and the desired matches.

Comment: @ChrisS that pared to 75 empty.  The number of chars in the line.  pattern = @"\b([^\\b]+)\b"; gave a strange parse of 3 words at word boundaries but some words included work boundaries.

Comment: You example says you want `MSCFX package propertiescu3u bin exet[p"R`4~fd` from the trash string, but isn't that just the entire trash string?

Comment: `\b` does not match characters - it is zero-width, just like `(?<=\w|^)(?=\W|$)`

Comment: @ChrisS In the sample the space represents a break between "words" found.  But it did not find the trash word.

Comment: @agent-j I am realizing my perception of \b was incorrect. I understand what you are telling me about 0 width.  But I still want everything between \b.

Comment: @Blam, I think everything inbetween `\b` would be the same as Regex.Split(s, @"\b"), which would return an array you could `string.Join("", array)` that would yield your original string.  `\b` is just not what you want.

Comment: @Blam - Looking at the big picture, assertions like `\G^$\b\B(?!)(?=)(?<!)(?<=)` only exist between characters. They stand still and ask a question. Its a `if()` statement in regex jargon. `\B` looks left and right for characters of the same kind. `\b` looks left and right for characters of different kind.

Comment: @sln I don't know regex well enough to know what you are telling me and I apologize.  Asking for not /b is totally confusing and wrong as I was not thinking of /b as zero width.  Regex.Split(s, @"\b") does what I asked but I asked the question wrong.  From that odd numbers of split is what I want and I also need the position.

Comment: @Blan - Split using `@"\b"` is roughtly equivalent to matching using `@"(.+?)\b"`. Then you can get the positions.

Comment: @snl that yields both the words and the splits so I only need the odd.    I may just throw away the even in the loop.  I need to test on some big files of odd even is always in synch.

Comment: @Blam - No need to do that. If you know what you want, just do `@"(\W+?)\b"` or `@"(\w+?)\b"`. Same difference. If you don't care and just want the odd, then this `@"(.+?)\b.+?\b"` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a word boundry `\B` would refer to adjacent items of the same ilk, iether word or not word.

You appear to want `\b(\w+|\W+)\b` because `((?:\B.\B)+)` will leave off end characters of the same ilk.

*edit:*

Re you update..

```
You could split with this [^\p{L}] *\p{Z} [^\p{L}]* or use  

(dosen't account for graphines) 
[\s\pP]* ([\pL\pN_-] (?: [\pL\pN_-] | \pP(?=[\pL\pN\pP_-]) )* )
  or
[\s[:punct:]]* (\w (?: \w | [[:punct:]](?=[\w[:punct:]]) )* )
```

Both yield

```
'hello'
'world'
'MSCFX'
'package.propertiescu3u'
'bin\exet[p"R4~fd'
'Would'
'like'
'MSCFX'
'package'
'propertiescu3u'
'bin'
'centra'
'exet[p"R4~fd'
```

Comment: The \W+ is matching on \b chars.  Please see update to answer.

Comment: I appreciate your help but don't follow "split with"  pattern = @"[^\p{L}] *\p{Z} [^\p{L}]*"; yields the whole line

Comment: Take out the spaces. `@"[^\p{L}]*\p{Z}[^\p{L}]*"`. Be warned, this will yield a different result than the other two regex posted.

Comment: Not the answer I used but you got my on the track of [^] so giving you the check.

Answer (score 1):

`\w` matches letters, digits, and `_` (underscore).  `\b` matches boundaries between `\w` characters and `\W` (non-word characters, `[^\w]`).  `\B` a boundary (it is always zero-width), so `\B+` is pointless.

**Edit:**  I'm still having trouble understanding exactly where you want to break up the words.

If you want to match anything except `.` (period) and whitespace, try this **exclusion** method:

```
[^.\s]+
```

If you want to include specific characters, try this **inclusion** method:

```
[-\w`~!@#$%^&*\[\]()\\\/]+
```

Comment: Thanks but \S+ is not a liberal enough parser.  \b will parse on . \

Comment: @Blam, not sure I understand yet, but you pretty much have two options, inclusion and exclusion... see my edit.

Comment: I hear you.   I so wish ^\b could be an inclusion.   In my brute force code it has a list of break characters. And the logic is simple.  Char is either a break or not.  If it is not a break char it becomes part of the current word.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just split the string on spaces, backslashes, and periods, like in your example?

```
// C#
string str = "MSCFX package.propertiescu3u bin\\exet[p\"R`4~fd"; // note the necessary escapes for \ and " 
var words = Regex.Split(str,@"[ \.\\]"); // split on spaces, periods, and backslashes
```

Comment: See problem statement "I know .NET string.parse might be faster but I need the match position also."

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand exactly what `\b` does.  Keep in mind that regexes can't read; the "word" in "word boundary" is arbitrarily defined as one or more letters, digits or underscores.  If your definition is different, `\b` is useless.

So what exactly do *you* consider a word? Looking at your updated question, I still don't see a usable pattern.  Do you just want to split on whitespace and periods?

```
pattern = @"(?<=^|[\s.])[^\s.]+(?=[\s.]|$)";
```

Applied to your test string:

```
MSCFX package.propertiescu3u bin\exet[p"R`4~fd
```

...it matches:

```
MSCFX
package
propertiescu3u
bin\exet[p"R`4~fd
```

Comment: A word is anything that is not \b.  It is that simple.  Every character is either a break or part of a word.

Comment: No, it's not that simple: "anything that is not \b" makes no sense.  If you can't come up with a clearer set of criteria than that, you're not going to be able to do this with a regex.

Comment: I agree not \b makes no sense.  I had an incorrect understanding of \b.   Sorry

Answer (score 1):

According to [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/)

```
([^\\b]*)
```

Works ``` MSCFX package.propertiescu3u bin\exet[p"R``4~fd ``` using ignorecase, singleline.

[image]

Comment: `[^\b]` matches any character except backspace. `\b` loses its normal meaning in a character class).  The opposite of `\b` is `\B`, but they're both zero-width assertions: the don't consume any characters when they match.

Comment: @AlanMoore there's actually a \\b there, SO was removing it

Comment: It's still not right. `[^\\b]` matches any characters except ```\``` or `b`.  Anyway, I'm pretty sure the OP wants to match four "words" within that string, not the whole string at once.

Comment: I tried what I think you told me to do but I got some results I do not expect.

Comment: Yeh I'm matching \ or b rather than \b.